# Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.0/firebase-app.js' does not provide an export named 'default'

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-authentication

I'm trying to set up and test google authentication for a webapp I'm working on. I've been having a lot of issues with getting the javascript functions running, and I'm not sure why. I use all CDN imports because I was having an error referencing firebase folders locally. Here are my files:

firebase-config.js

```
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import firebase from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.0/firebase-app.js"; 
import { getAnalytics } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.0/firebase-analytics.js";

const firebaseConfig = {
 [config keys]
};

// Initialize Firebase app
const fb_app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig); // returns an app 
const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
export {fb_app};
```

signin.js

```
import {fb_app} from "/src/firebase-config.js";

import { getAuth, signInWithPopup, GoogleAuthProvider } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.4.0/firebase-auth.js";

fb_app; // I was getting an error that the firebase app isn't initialized, so I placed this here to see if it was work. I am not sure this is the correct way to call the app in this file. 

const auth = getAuth();
const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider(); 

signInWithPopup(auth, provider)
  .then((result) => {
    console.log("Signing User In...");
    // This gives you a Google Access Token. You can use it to access the Google API.
    const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromResult(result);
    const token = credential.accessToken;
    // The signed-in user info.
    const user = result.user;
    // ...
  }).catch((error) => {
    // Handle Errors here.
    const errorCode = error.code;
    const errorMessage = error.message;
    // The email of the user's account used.
    const email = error.email;
    // The AuthCredential type that was used.
    const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromError(error);
    // ...
  });
document.getElementById("signInButton").onclick = signInWithPopup(auth, provider); // this is how I am importing the function to the html.
```

index.html

```
<body>
        <div class="loginbox">
            <h1>Login</h1>
            <form>
                <div id="google-signin"> 
                    <button id="signInButton">Login with Google -></button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <!-- <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
        <script src="/src/signin.jsx"></script> -->
    </body>
```

Any help whatsoever would be appreciated. I am very new to learning this stuff, so I understand if I may have unintentionally done something wrong. I have gotten a lot of different errors relating to smaller minor details, but I genuinely don't understand why this error would be arising. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need more details about the libraries you are using. the error originates here

```
import firebase from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.0/firebase-app.js";
```

you are trying to import the `default` object from the library by not using the parenthesis import. which is not provided from the firebase library.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

Comment: Just to add: using `9.x.x` on your code means that it's the modular-based version of the Firebase SDK. The default import would have worked if you used anything lower than that version. Reference: https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade.